# Flutter Firebase: I want to stream the details of the logged in user across the app using Stream provider

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider, flutter-streambuilder

I'm getting the below error:

```
The return type 'AuthUser?' isn't a 'User?', as required by the closure's context.
```

From the below code:

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth authInstance = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<User?> get currentUser => authInstance.authStateChanges().map(
        (User? firebaseUser) => (firebaseUser != null) ? AuthUser.fromFirebaseUser(user: firebaseUser) : null,
      );
}
```

Below is the code for the model class:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthUser {
  String? uid;
  String? email;
  String? userName;

  AuthUser({
    required this.uid,
    required this.email,
    required this.userName,
  });

  AuthUser.fromFirebaseUser({User? user}) {
    uid = user!.uid;
    email = user.email;
    userName = user.displayName;
  }
}
```

I would also like to know how to consume this stream using the `StreamProvider<AuthUser>.value`.

Are either of `Consumer` widget or the `Provider.of(context)` widget appropriate to access the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stream is mapping the `User` model from Firebase to your `AuthUser` model.
So you need to change the return type of the `currentUser` getter.

Change this:

```dart
Stream<User?> get currentUser => authInstance.authStateChanges().map(
        (User? firebaseUser) => (firebaseUser != null) ? AuthUser.fromFirebaseUser(user: firebaseUser) : null,
);
```

to this:

```dart
Stream<AuthUser?> get currentUser => authInstance.authStateChanges().map(
        (User? firebaseUser) => (firebaseUser != null) ? AuthUser.fromFirebaseUser(user: firebaseUser) : null,
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Victor Eronmosele! As always brilliant and perfect!

Comment: But when I try to access the uid or displayname or email, I'm unable to access them. `final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);`
`final currentLoggedInUser = authService.user;`

Comment: Now if I try to make use of `currentLoggedInUser.uid` if doesn't gives me either the uid or displayName or email. Could you please help with this @Victor Eronmosele. Once again thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Auth have is own storage that store all this information all you need is to is to declear a global users then asses the infomation any place in the app...

example

```
User users
```

then example of authentication

```
final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
      );
      users = (await auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      if (users == null) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print('this is error .......$e');
      return null;
    }
```